# How to get the offset of a given CPU register in Rust

Tags: c, rust, ptrace

As an exercise, I've been trying to use Rust's `nix::sys::ptrace::ptrace` (which is pretty much identical to C's ptrace) to emulate `strace`'s syscall logging functionality by reading the contents of the RAX/RBX/RCX/RDX registers at the time of each syscall.  My desired output would be something similar to this:

```
Found syscall: 4
Arg1: 1
Arg2: Hello World!
```

From the examples I've found online, it seems that a combination of `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` and `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` would be best for accomplishing this (maybe `PTRACE_GETREGS` too?), but I'm having a hard time understanding how to satisfy the 3rd argument that I need to pass to these functions in order to make it work.

`ptrace`'s man pages list this example demonstrating the proper usage:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT/PEEKDATA/PEEKUSER, pid, addr, 0);
```

The man page just says, "Read a word at the address `addr` in the tracee's memory." But what is `addr` supposed to be?  How can I determine the correct address to satisfy this argument?

The examples that I've found online all have something like:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, sizeof(long)*ORIG_EAX, 0);
```

or

```
ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, somenumber*RAX, 0)
```

How can I find/calculate the offset of these registers during runtime? (in Rust!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's been a long time since I poked Linux kernel (Mac user now). Buf if I remember it correctly then ...

## Kernel headers

Install kernel headers with something like `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. Let's say that you're on `x86_64-linux-gnu` (guess based on your `rax` interest).

Open `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/reg.h` header:

```c
...
#ifdef __x86_64__
/* Index into an array of 8 byte longs returned from ptrace for
   location of the users' stored general purpose registers.  */

# define R15    0
# define R14    1
# define R13    2
# define R12    3
# define RBP    4
# define RBX    5
# define R11    6
# define R10    7
# define R9     8
# define R8     9
# define RAX    10
...
```

And the comment says:

> Index into an array of 8 byte longs returned from ptrace for location of the users' stored general purpose registers.

All those macros (`RAX`, `RCX`, ...) define **indexes** for particular registers. And because each one is 8 byte long (`x86_64` only), the offset is `8 * $index`. In case of `rax` register, the offset is calculcated as `8 * RAX = 8 * 10 = 80`. `80` is what you should use for the `addr` argument in the `ptrace` function call. This is how it works. Be aware that it differs for other architectures, etc.

## PTRACE_*

`PTRACE_PEEKUSER` - use for registers and other debug info.

`PTRACE_PEEKDATA` - use for program data & code.

`PTRACE_PEEKTEXT` - `man ptrace` (Linux) says - *Copy the word data to the address addr in the tracee's memory. As for `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT` and `PTRACE_PEEKDATA`, these two requests are currently equivalent.* That's because Linux doesn't have separate address spaces for text and data.

## Rust & PTRACE_PEEKUSER

The `nix` crate offers [getregs](https://docs.rs/nix/0.13.0/nix/sys/ptrace/fn.getregs.html) function to read all of them. It returns `libc` [user_regs_struct](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.50/libc/struct.user_regs_struct.html). Which is supported for Linux only:

- [x86 user_regs_struct](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/0.2.50/src/unix/notbsd/linux/other/b32/x86.rs#L34)
- [x86_64 user_regs_struct](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/0.2.50/src/unix/notbsd/linux/other/b64/x86_64.rs#L115)

`libc` crate also contains those indexes as well:

- [x86 indexes](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/0.2.50/src/unix/notbsd/linux/other/b32/x86.rs#L843)
- [x86_64 indexes](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/0.2.50/src/unix/notbsd/linux/other/b64/x86_64.rs#L715)

If you're interested in one register only, you can use this index to calculate offset / addr for the [ptrace](https://docs.rs/nix/0.13.0/nix/sys/ptrace/fn.ptrace.html) function. Multiply it with `8` (`#[cfg(target_arch = "x86_64")]`) / `4` (`#[cfg(target_arch = "x86")]`) and use `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` to read it (see [Request](https://docs.rs/nix/0.13.0/nix/sys/ptrace/enum.Request.html)).

## Rust & PTRACE_PEEKDATA

Read [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6/2538212#2538212). In other words, you're interested in `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, ... registers. The `nix` crate provides specialized [read](https://docs.rs/nix/0.13.0/nix/sys/ptrace/fn.read.html) function, which [internally calls](https://docs.rs/nix/0.13.0/src/nix/sys/ptrace/linux.rs.html#399-401) `ptrace` function with `PTRACE_PEEKDATA`.

## nix crate

`ptrace` function is deprecated. Documentation note:

> Deprecated since 0.10.0: usages of ptrace() should be replaced with the specialized helper functions instead

You should use specialized functions like `getregs` & `read`. You can find list of them [in the documentation](https://docs.rs/nix/0.13.0/nix/sys/ptrace/index.html#functions).